# told vs have told in a sentence

Tags: phrases, past-tense, present-tense

How do you say the next sentence?

1) I told him to stay on the path while he was hiking, but he wandered off into the forest and was bitten by a snake

2) I told him to stay on the path while he was hiking, but he has wandered off into the forest and has been bitten by a snake

3) I have told him to stay on the path while he was hiking, but he wandered off into the forest and was bitten by a snake

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you mean

Comment: Each of these variants gives a different version of when you told him relative to when he wandered and now.  You can't pick a best answer without knowing what you want to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I told him while* suggests that you warned him **as** he was hiking. *I have told him* suggests a different timing, that your warning is **relevant** to the current topic but didn't necessarily happen at the same time.

Thus, if you were with him on the trail when you told him, the simple past tense is better. But if you gave him a standing warning that he later ignored, the perfect tense (*I have told*) is better.  You can even write *I had told him* to emphasize that your warning was in the past.

Answer (score 0):

First, *have* / *has* + past participle = *present* perfect, not past perfect.  Past perfect is in the form *had* + past participle.  Often, the present perfect suggests an action that commenced at some point in the past and continues to have an effect up to the present.

The first sentence suggests a sequence of events that occurred in the past and, pragmatically, no longer have any effect.

In the second sentence, the speaker performed some action in the past; the other person, however, remains off the path and, presumably, still smarting from his snake bite.

Therefore, either of these two sentences works, depending on the intended meaning.  The third sentence is probably not grammatical.  The first clause sets a context (as it does in each of these sentences) in the present.  However, the present-tense context is given for something that occurred beforehand.  Regardless of when or why one might mix and match tenses, I don't think this is the kind of thing anyone would say — and that's only due to the distribution of tenses, not the verbs or the meaning or anything else.

Edit: On second thought, the big problem with #3 is the mixing of tenses in the first half. *I told him to stay on the path while he was hiking*... Does that mean I said, "Listen, Jack, you have to stay on the path while you were hiking"? No, I *can't* say that. However, *I've told him not to do it, but he did it anyway* could probably work — e.g.,

A: He just did it.
B: What?? Why haven't you told him not to?
A: I *have* told him not to. But he did it anyway.

Does the bigger pause make it sound better?  I don't know.  Can B switch tenses like that?  I'm not sure B *would*, but I think B *could*.

Answer (score -1):

1) has the correct tense agreement. Both "told" and "wandered off" are past tense verbs.

In 2), "told" is past tense and "has wandered" is past perfect tense. In 3), "have told" is past perfect tense and "wandered" is past tense. Typically, you want the verb tenses to agree, but it depends on exactly what you're trying to say. For example, you wouldn't combine present with past by saying something like, "I am telling him to stay on the path, but he wandered off into the forest and was bitten by a snake."

Comment: You *don't* always want them to agree. I can think of times when you would use

Comment: Correct, you don't always want them to agree. But like I said, typically you do.

Comment: Not if you want to show that the told-ing and wander-ing were not at the same time.  Then you need the proper tenses.

Comment: Agreed. I was assuming from the 3 simple examples that the author wanted to keep it simple and make the verb tenses agree.